# vim: Using matchadd 'globally' (i.e. highlighting a bunch of lines)

Tags: vim, pattern-matching

I have a file that looks something like this

```
def foo bar {{
   // some stuff in here that shouldn't have }}; in it
}};
```

And I'd like to syntax highlight certain types of these blocks. My first order approximation was this:

```
highlight DefFoo ctermfg=darkgreen                  
let defFoo = 'def foo .* {{.*}};'             
call matchadd('DefFoo', defFoo)
```

However, the only stuff that gets highlighted is the first line `def foo bar {{` . I've been trying to find a way to execute a `matchadd` that searches globally, but I've been failing. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.` does not match new lines. `\_.` does on the other hand. So your pattern would be:

```
def foo \_.* {{\_.*}};
```

I find for one off matches using something like the following to be nice:

```
:match Error /foo-pattern-here/
```

It can be cleared with

```
:match
```

Note that `:match` with an expensive pattern may cause the matched text to not highlight properly on some screen redraws. Either adjust your pattern or up your `'redrawtime'`

For more information:

```
:h :match
:h /\_.
```

Comment: Just tried it out and it seems to work like a charm. The main reason I'm using matchadd() instead of match is because there are actually several different types of definitions I want to highlight all in different colors. IIRC I can't do simultaneous matches with match.